# Kontraŭaj signifoj de 'aperi'

Tags: word-difference

PIV kaj ReVo donas ne nur malsaman sed kontraŭan signifon por la vorto *aperi*:

> **PIV**:  [aperi](http://vortaro.net/#aperi) 4. Sin montri ia aŭ tia, kia oni efektive estas (male
>   al ŝajni)
>
> **ReVo**:  [aperi](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/aper.html#aper.0i) 2. Sin montri ia aŭ tia, ŝajni

Ambaŭ donas la samajn ekzemplo-frazojn (ĉiuj Zamenhofaj):

*aperi senkulpa; aperi pli granda; aperi mensoganto; miaj rimedoj de solvo aperos eble kiel tro simplaj al la leganto; Esperanto vere aperas kiel sola kandidato por lingvo internacia; kiel grandega malhelpo aperos la reciproka envio de la popoloj; tia ŝanĝo aperas kiel tute neakceptebla*.

Tamen, la papera Plena Vortaro (1980) donas la saman signifon kiel la reta ReVo.
La papera Nova Plena Ilustrita Vortaro (2002) donas la saman signifon kiel la reta PIV.

Ĉu iu povas klarigi tiun kontraŭdiron? Kiu el la du signifoj estas la ĝusta? Ĉu tiu paradokso detruos la universon?

Answer (score 1):

Kaj "aperi X" kaj "ŝajni X" signifas ke la situacio aspektas kiel X estas vera, sed la diferenco estas la certeco pri la vereco de X. En [PIV la difino de ŝajni](http://vortaro.net/#%C5%9Dajni) estas

> I. Ekstere aspekti simile al io alia, [...]
>
> II. Esti opiniata, kredata, supozata, **kvankam ne certa**

Do oni uzas la unuan signifon de *ŝajni* kiam oni volas esprimi ke X fakte ne veras kaj oni uzas la duan signifon kiam oni volas esprimi ke X nur eble veras. Aliflanke, la vorto "aperi" ne esprimas dubon pri la vereco de X. Uzante la difinojn de PIV, mi kreis la suban desegnaĉon:

[image: sajni_kaj_aperi]

Mi kredas ke vortaro.net skribas

> aperi IV. Sin montri ia aŭ tia, kia oni efektive estas (male al ŝajni)

por diri ke "I. ŝajni" estas tiel la malo de "IV. aperi".

Tamen, la limoj inter "ne vera" "eble vera" kaj "vera" estas malklaraj (en la reala vivo), do "II. ŝajni" povas ekzemple kelkfoje anstataŭi "IV. aperi". Tial ReVo povas prave diri ke ŝajni estas sinonimo de aperi.

Answer (score 0):

ReVo estas farita baze de la senkopirajtiĝinta Plena Vortaro. La reta PIV estas ekzakte la sama kiel la NPIV, do viaj eltrovoj pri tio estas pravaj. Mi pensas ke la fakta diferenco estas ke ŝajno temas pri interpreto aŭ iluzio, dum apero temas pri fakta fasado. La praktika uzo estas ege simila, do tiel ili ambaŭ pravas: se ili ne estus ege similaj kiel prave diras PV/ReVo, ne estus senco por PIV montri kiel ili malsamas.

Answer (score 0):

> **aperi** kiel = havi la (supozeblan) aspekton/eksteraĵon de
>
> Kie *aperi* ofte estas ŝanĝebla, dumtempa, provizora, **nepruvata**.

Kaj tio povas indiki ke la vera karaktero *ne* estas tia, aŭ - male- ekmontriĝas tia.

1. [poste evidentiĝi] *Esperanto vere aperas kiel sola kandidato*
2. [ŝajni antaŭe, unuavide] *La fripono aperis tute sincera*

Comment: Ĉu vi diras ke la difino en PIV estas malĝusta?

Comment: @svendvn `PIV aperi 4` oni povus formuli/miskompreni(?) kiel _evidentiĝi_ PIV 3; ŝanĝanta percepto. Ekz. _"Esperanto vere aperas kiel sola kandidato"_. Tamen ekz. _"La fripono aperis tute honesta." estas same ĝusta, bezonante alian difinon: _alia ol kia tio efektive estas._ Mi trovas la difinojn en PIV, precipe _tia-kia_ ne tre klara.